# Creating a new div onclick wordpress+ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a link in worpress page

```
<a onclick="show_trend()" >Trend</a>
```

and i am calling an ajax function onclick.

```
function show_trend() {

    // This does the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'render_admin_charts_page',

        },
        success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

what i want to do when calling this function is display a div section .for that ,this is my function

```
function render_admin_charts_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="em-bookings-events">
            <h2><?php esc_html_e('Event Booking Report','dbem'); ?></h2>        
            <?php em_bookings_events_table(); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

ajax function is calling but not rendering to div

Answer (score 1):

To add action for Wordpress AJAX

If you needed to create an AJAX handler for an "render_admin_charts_page" request, you would create a hook like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_render_admin_charts_page', 'yourfunction' );

function yourfunction() { ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="em-bookings-events">
            <h2><?php esc_html_e('Event Booking Report','dbem'); ?></h2>        
            <?php em_bookings_events_table(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php   // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response
}
```

Using the above example, any time an AJAX request is sent to WordPress, and the request's 'action' property is set to 'render_admin_charts_page', this hook will be automatically executed. For example, the following code would execute the above hook:

```
jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'render_admin_charts_page',              
    }, 
    function(response){
        alert('The server responded: ' + response);
    }
);
```

Comment: ok. now in consol i am getting all the content from the file.can you help me instead of creating div in the same page.creating a new page?

Comment: can you pls elaborate ?

Comment: What i am doing now is creating a new div in the same page from where i am calling the function.can u pls tell me how to create a new page and create div in that page?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to declare this function, `add_action( 'wp_ajax_render_admin_charts_page', 'yourfunction' );`, in another file?

If yes, then you can place this piece of code in functions.php of your active theme:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_render_admin_charts_page', 'yourfunction' );

function yourfunction() { ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="em-bookings-events">
            <h2><?php esc_html_e('Event Booking Report','dbem'); ?></h2>        
            <?php em_bookings_events_table(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php   // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response
}
```

If you want to place it in another PHP file, for that you don't need to create a hook for AJAX. Just place your code in a PHP file and place it in your active theme, and use the below code for AJAX:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: fav_url ,  // path of that file 
    type: 'GET',        
    timeout: 20000,
    error: function(){
        alert("Error loading user's attending event.");
    },
    success: function(html){}
})
```

Comment: actually i am rendering in admin side. as u said  ahve created new file chart.php  then wrote  my function and add_action()

Comment: then in ajax url:chart.php  ... this is what u meant?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am doing same thing but instead of using wp_ajax_render I am using wp ajax nopriv function and it is working for me.